# Validating Null and Empty Strings using Jersey

Tags: rest, maven, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

Can I have a web deployment descriptor file, web.xml, with a Jersey project that runs on top of a Grizzly container? I want to constrain my resource to ensure that input is provided, using @NotNull.

Some context...

I'm using Jersey 2.19 to implement a REST API.

Following the 'Getting Started' section of the user guide I successfully created a new Jersey project that runs on top of a Grizzly container using a Jersey-provided maven archetype.

I have also successfully implemented some bean validation by annotating a resource with various built-in constraints.

I would like add a @NotNull constraint to my resource and for it to mean that input is required - i.e. for an empty string to fail this validation constraint.

The [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation002.htm#GKCRG) refers to making a change to web.xml but there isn't one in my project. I see from the user guide that if I'd created a JavaEE web application instead then the web.xml file would be present.

Can I add one? Or is there another way to validate empty strings in the way I want?

**UPDATE**

Chapter 18 of the Jersey User Guide does not tell me what I need to know. The [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation002.htm#GKCRG) indicates that I need to set javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL in the web.xml file. What is the equivalent of that if I don't have a web.xml?

Comment: Can you point out the exact part of the documentation you are referring to, that tell you to use web.xml for what you are trying to do?

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html section 1.4

Comment: I thought the link would be related to actual bean validation.  You are just pointing to the getting started page which has nothing to do with bean-validation. Do you have the part of the documentation (in chapter 18) that actually involves bean-validation? I couldn't find any reference at all to web.xml. The only configuration code example uses a standalone `ResourceConfig`, which is what you are using. So maybe I am not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry it's the section in the Java EE tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation002.htm#GKCRG. I've clarified my post.

Comment: See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html

Comment: That is section 18 of the guide, which I've read over and over. Can you be more specific - what am I looking for, which sub-section?

Comment: 18.1 for dependency, 18.3 for configuration. And just read the whole thing for other general information and features. The chapter isn't that long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82464/discussion-between-ksl-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` is a JSF parameters so it will have no affect on Jersey. Since The default implementation for bean validation with Jersey is [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/), you can use it's annotation [`@NotEmpty`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html). It should serve similar purpose as the JSF parameter (to fail on empty strings).